# SAS minimum of all rows

Tags: sas

I have a file with 25 rows like:

```
Model   Cena (zl)   Nagrywanie fimow HD Optyka - krotnosc zoomu swiatlo obiektywu przy najkrotszej ogniskowej   Wielkosc LCD (cale)
Lumix DMC-LX3   1699    tak 2.5 2   3
Lumix DMC-GH1 + LUMIX G VARIO HD 14-140mm/F4.0-5.8 ASPH./MEGA O.I.S 5199    tak 10  4   3
```

And I wrote:

```
DATA lab_1;

INFILE 'X:\aparaty.txt' delimiter='09'X;

INPUT Model $ Cena Nagrywanie $ Optyka Wielkosc_LCD Nagr_film;

f_skal = MAX(Cena - 1500, Optyka - 10, Wielkosc_LCD - 1, Nagr_film - 1) + 1/1000*(Cena - 1500 + Optyka - 10 + Wielkosc_LCD - 1 + Nagr_film - 1);

*rozw = MIN(f_skal);
*rozw = f_skal[,<:>];

PROC SORT;
BY DESCENDING f_skal;

PROC PRINT DATA = lab_1;

data _null_;
set lab_1;
FILE 'X:\aparatyNOWE.txt'; DLM='09'x;
PUT Model= $ Cena Nagrywanie $ Optyka Wielkosc_LCD Nagr_film f_skal;
RUN;
```

I need to find the lowest value of f_skal and I don't know how because min(f_skal) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In a data step, the min function only looks at one row at a time - if you feed it several variables, it will give you the minimum value out of all of those variables for that row, but you can't use it to look at values across multiple rows (unless you get data from multiple rows into 1 row first, e.g. via use of retain / lag).

One way of calculating statistics in SAS across a whole dataset is to use proc means / proc summary, e.g.:

```
proc summary data = lab1;
  var f_skal;
  output out = min_val min=;
run;
```

This will create a dataset called min_val in your work library, and the value of f_skal in that dataset will be the minimum from anywhere in the dataset lab1.

If you would rather create a macro variable containing the minimum value, so that you can use it in subsequent code, one way of doing that is to use proc sql instead:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select min(f_skal) into :min_value from lab1;
    quit;
run;

%put Minimum value = &min_value;
```

In proc sql the behaviour of min is different - here it compares values across rows, the way you were trying to use it.